# Normalize scipy csr matrix columns

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, normalize

I have data that contains a bunch of categorical features. I want to one-hot encode the categorical features, but I've got a memory error because the categorical features have too many levels. The solution I found was to use the csr format and I understood why it is memory efficient.

```
df['gender'].value_counts()

>> male      68208
   female    68089
   unknown    13703
   Name: gender, dtype: int64

from pandas.core.categorical import Categorical
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

categories = Categorical(df['gender']) # male, female, and unknown
N = len(df['gender'])
row_numbers = np.arange(N, dtype=np.int)
ones = np.ones((N,))
dummies = csr_matrix( (ones, (row_numbers, categories.codes)) )
dummies.todense()

>> matrix([[1., 0., 0.],
           [0., 1., 0.],
           [1., 0., 0.],
            ...,
           [1., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 1.],
           [0., 0., 1.]])
```

The problem is, I have to normalize the features as I am using the KNN algorithm. I tried to normalize the categorical features using scikit-learn's normalize, but it was not done the way I expected.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
dummies = normalize(dummies, axis=0, norm='l2')
dummies.todense()

>> matrix([[0.00382897, 0.        , 0.        ],
          [0.        , 0.00854264, 0.        ],
          [0.00382897, 0.        , 0.        ],
          ...,
          [0.00382897, 0.        , 0.        ],
          [0.        , 0.        , 0.00383232],
          [0.        , 0.        , 0.00383232]])
```

The non-zero values in the matrix are too small so obviously they were not produced by (x-mean(X)) / std(X). I suspect that the normalization above was performed that way because scikit-learn does not want the matrix to lose its sparse form.

I want to understand how the matrix above was normalized. More specifically, I want to know how sklearn.preprocessing.normalize normalizes sparse matrices in scipy's csr format.

I appreciate your help in advance!

*ADDED: By normalization, I expected something like this:*

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0])

mean = array.mean()
std = array.std()
normalized_array = (array-mean)/std
```

As we have two unique values, one and zero, after normalization the ones should be replaced with a positive number and the zeros should be replaced with a negative number.

```
normalized_array
>> array([ 0.57735027,  0.57735027,  0.57735027, -1.73205081])
```

Comment: What kinds of values do you expect?  Maybe you could demonstrate the desired normalization with a small numpy array.

Comment: Hi. I appreciate your comment. I added the normalization I though sklearn.preprocessing's normalize does.

Comment: I just want to understand how sklearn.preprocessing's normalize performs normalization of csr matrices. It seems like the binary values are scaled by a certain factor(or a statistic) and I want to know what the factor is.

Comment: With that shift with the mean you no longer have a sparse matrix, What does `normalize` do with `dummies.A`?

Comment: The docs say it just works on the non-zero values.  Quick testing shows that it produces the same norm for a dense array and a sparse one.  For the dense you can ask for `return_norm`.  For an array of just 1s, the norms appear to be the square root of the number of nonzero values in column (or row).  That is, `n` ones are normalized by `sqrt(n)`.

Comment: Hi. I really appreciate your answer. You are right. It just scales each column by the column's norm. I believe it does not center each column(subtracting mean) since it wants to keep its sparse form. I am not sure it is a correct way to normalize a column as columns are not centered.